# how to fix this Value Error ' ValueError: decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer,'?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, model, face-recognition

I'm new at deep learning and i follow tutorial about face detection.

```
model = canaro.models.createSimpsonsModel(IMG_SIZE=IMG_SIZE, channels=channels, output_dim=len(characters), 
                                         loss='binary_crossentropy', decay=1e-7, learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.9,
                                         nesterov=True)
```

ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
WARNING:absl:`lr` is deprecated, please use `learning_rate` instead, or use the legacy optimizer, e.g.,tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD.
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
ValueError: decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer, pleasecheck the docstring for valid arguments, or use the legacy optimizer, e.g., tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD.

I already tried follow some steps but i dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use a quite old deep learning library which is clearly out-dated and not maintained lately. The error you saw was due to the API used by that specific library was written in an older version of tensorflow (<=2.3), which is now deprecated. If you want to fix that, you have to either manually downgrade your tensorflow or modify the source code of that library `canaro`.

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned elsewhere, the `decay` argument has been deprecated for all optimizers since Keras 2.3, whose [release notes](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.3.0) explicitly suggest using [LearningRateSchedule](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/schedules/LearningRateSchedule) objects instead.

Since you can't obviously modify the *canaro* source code (well... you could, but it'd be very bad practice, and definitely **not** recommended), I see two options:

1. downgrade Tensorflow to a version that employs a Keras backend <2.3
2. upgrade *canaro* to a version that supports TF 2.3+, if possible

For those who got to this question after a Google search and can still modify their source code (they are not especially worried about *canaro*, that is) here you are an example snippet:

**TF<2.3 - style**

```
import tensorflow as tf
epochs = 50
learning_rate = 0.01
decay_rate = learning_rate / epochs
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate, decay=decay_rate)
```

**TF>=2.3 - style**

```
import tensorflow as tf
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate=0.01,
    decay_steps=10000,
    decay_rate=0.9)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
```

Answer (score 1):

canaro.models.createSimpsonsModel is nothing but to create a model. Since you are only using it for tutorial, a simpler way is to create a model to pass that error so that you can follow the tutorial. Here is an example for your reference, you may need to change the layers and parameters based on your request.

## Create the model with updated optimizer syntax

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
```

## Create the model

```
model = models.Sequential()
```

## Convolutional layers

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(80, 80, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

# Flatten the output to feed into dense layers
model.add(layers.Flatten())
```

## Dense layers

```
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))  # Using sigmoid for binary classification
```

## Compile the model

```
learning_rate = 0.001
momentum = 0.9
nesterov = True
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=momentum, nesterov=nesterov)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

## Print the model summary (optional)

```
model.summary()
```