# ValueError: decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer, pleasecheck the docstring for valid arguments, or use the legacy optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm pretty new on deep learning and I got some errors.
Here's my code:

```py
import os
import caer
import canaro
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import gc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler

IMG_SIZE = (80,80)
channels = 1
char_path = r"simpsons_dataset"
char_dict = {}
for char in os.listdir(char_path):
    char_dict[char] = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(char_path,char)))
# sorth in descending order
char_dict = caer.sort_dict(char_dict, descending=True)
# print(char_dict)
characters = []
count = 0
for i in char_dict:
    characters.append(i[0])
    count += 1
    if count >= 10:
        break
print(characters)
# create the training data
train = caer.preprocess_from_dir(char_path, characters, channels=channels, IMG_SIZE=IMG_SIZE, isShuffle=True)
len(train)
plt.figure(figsize=(30,30))
plt.imshow(train[0][0], cmap='gray')
plt.show()
featureSet, labels = caer.sep_train(train, IMG_SIZE=IMG_SIZE)
# Normalize the featureSet ==> (0,1)
featureSet = caer.normalize(featureSet)
labels = to_categorical(labels, len(characters))
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = caer.train_val_split(featureSet, labels, val_ratio=.2)
del train
del featureSet
del labels
gc.collect()
BATCH_SIZE = 32
EPOCHS = 10
# Image data generator
datagen = canaro.generators.imageDataGenerator()
train_gen = datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
# Creating the model. returns the compiled model
model = canaro.models.createSimpsonsModel(IMG_SIZE=IMG_SIZE, channels=channels, output_dim=len(characters),loss='binary_crossentropy', decay=1e-6, learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.9, nesterov=None)
model.summary()
callbacks_list = [LearningRateScheduler(canaro.lr_schedule())]
training = model.fit(train_gen, steps_per_epoch = len(x_train)//BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data = (x_val, y_val), validation_steps=len(y_val)//BATCH_SIZE, callbacks = callbacks_list)
```

The error I get:

```py
WARNING:absl:`lr` is deprecated in Keras optimizer, please use `learning_rate` or use the legacy optimizer, e.g.,tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD. <br>
Traceback (most recent call last): <br>
model = canaro.models.createSimpsonsModel(IMG_SIZE=IMG_SIZE, channels=channels, output_dim=len(characters),
optimizer = SGD(lr=learning_rate, decay=decay, momentum=momentum, nesterov=nesterov)
ValueError: decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer, pleasecheck the docstring for valid arguments, or use the legacy optimizer
```

I've searched for the solution but still don't have the right answer.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using code that references old libraries.
The decay argument is deprecated for optimizers since Keras 2.3.

You basically have two options

- downgrade Tensorflow to a version with Keras backend <2.3
- upgrade canaro to a version that supports TF >=2.3

Another answer was given here which also points out ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74734685/how-to-fix-this-value-error-valueerror-decay-is-deprecated-in-the-new-keras-o)), that if you are not married to canaro you can use folowing options to get your code to wokr:

**TF<2.3 - style**

```
import tensorflow as tf
epochs = 50
learning_rate = 0.01
decay_rate = learning_rate / epochs
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate, decay=decay_rate)
```

**TF>=2.3 - style**

```
import tensorflow as tf
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate=0.01,
    decay_steps=10000,
    decay_rate=0.9)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning suggests to use `learning_rate` or the legacy optimizer, e.g.,tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD. Try out the code below it should fix the error.

`optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD(lr=learning_rate, decay=decay, momentum=momentum, nesterov=nesterov)`