# ValueError: decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, valueerror

```py
INIT_LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 10
BS = 8

opt = Adam(learning_rate=INIT_LR,decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,metrics=["accuracy"])
R = model.fit_generator(
trainAug.flow(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=BS),
steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) // BS,
validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
validation_steps=len(X_test) // BS,
epochs=EPOCHS)
```

that is my code some part and it gives this
ValueError: `decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer` How I solve this issue and instead of the `decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS` what can I use to same as above

Comment: Did you check the docstring? You'll see it is `weight_decay` instead of `decay`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fix this Value Error ' ValueError: decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer,'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74734685/how-to-fix-this-value-error-valueerror-decay-is-deprecated-in-the-new-keras-o)